# Multithread client server chat on sockets. Load test. recv failed

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Hello guys have client server chat and i try to write load test on it. i use my protocol it looks like XMPP. I send XML and parse it. If I start the server, for some users it works properly. But I have am load-testing and am starting a lot of users and sending messages from each one. In the test I do not create new client, i'm only instantiating an output thread with an output stream and sending messages using it. The server sends a message that it recieved to all users, so I create one user that listens to the other users. And sometimes I recieve the exception: **Software caused connection abort: recv failed** This is my console:

```
06:55:49 Guest 9 (online)  says : Hello Server. Message number^4
06:55:49 Guest 9 (online)  says : Hello Server. Message number^5
06:55:49 Guest 11 (online)  says : Hello Server. Message number^0
06:55:49 Guest 4 (online)  says : Hello Server. Message number^6
ERROR ServerThread - Error in reading from stream: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
ERROR ServerThread - Error in reading from stream: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
06:55:49 Guest 9 (online)  says : Hello Server. Message number^6
```

This is my serverThread. I skip the part where it is waiting for users.

```
public class ServerThread implements Runnable {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ServerThread.class);
    private XMLProtocol protocol;
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader input;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private static Date date;
    private String username;
    private String status = "online";
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
    private String buffer = "";
    private JAXBContext jaxbContext;
    private Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller;

    public ServerThread(Socket s) throws SAXException, IOException, JAXBException {
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(XMLProtocol.class);
        out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        username = "Guest " + Server.getUserCounter();
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
        Server.addUser(username, out);
        date = new Date();
        socket = s;
        new Thread(this);
    }

    public void run() {

        try {
            while (true) {
                if (input.ready()) {
                    if (buffer.length() <= 256) {
                        if ((buffer = input.readLine()).toString().endsWith("</XMLProtocol>")) {

                            protocol = new XMLProtocol();
                            jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                            protocol = (XMLProtocol) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(buffer)));

                            switch (ChatCommands.valueOf(protocol.getStatus())) {
                            case LOGIN: {
                                Server.sendToAll(Server.buildResponce("User: " + this.username + " Has been changed nickname on "
                                        + protocol.getContent()));
                                this.username = protocol.getContent();
                                break;
                            }
                            case STATUS: {
                                Server.sendToAll(Server.buildResponce("The user: " + this.username + " Is now:" + protocol.getContent()));
                                this.status = protocol.getContent();
                                break;
                            }
                            case LOGOUT: {
                                Server.sendResponce(Server.buildResponce(ResponseCommands.DISCONNECT), out);
                                quit();
                                break;
                            }
                            default: {
                                LOG.trace("Getting message from user: " + username + " recived message: " + protocol.getContent());
                                date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                                Server.sendToAll(Server.buildResponce(dateFormat.format(date.getTime()) + " " + username + " ("
                                        + this.status + ") " + " says : " + protocol.getContent()));
                                break;
                            }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        Server.sendResponce(Server.buildResponce(ResponseCommands.SENDING_FAILED), out);
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("Error in reading from stream: " + e);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            LOG.error("Error in Marshalling: " + e);
        } finally {
            try {
                Server.sendResponce(Server.buildResponce(ResponseCommands.UNEXPECTED), out);
                quit();
                LOG.trace("Socket closed");
            } catch (IOException | JAXBException e) {
                LOG.error("Socket no closed" + e);
            }
        }
    }

    public void quit() throws IOException, JAXBException {
        Server.sendToAll(Server.buildResponce("User: " + this.username + " quited"));
        Server.removeUser(out);
        socket.shutdownInput();
        socket.shutdownOutput();
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

And this is my test

```
public class ServerLoadTest {

    private static ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1000);
    private static Socket s[] = new Socket[50];// = new Socket();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, UnknownHostException, IOException, InterruptedException,
            XMLStreamException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
        exec.execute(new TestServerThread()); // start Server thread
        Thread.sleep(500); // wait till Server starts.

        s[0] = new Socket("localhost", 4444);

        exec.execute(new InputThread(s[0], new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s[0].getInputStream())))); // Start
                                                                                                                // one
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            exec.execute(new TestClientThread());           
        }
    }

}

class TestClientThread implements Runnable {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TestClientThread.class);
    private XMLProtocol protocol;
    private JAXBContext jaxbContext;
    private Marshaller jaxbMarshaller;
    private Socket socket;
    private OutputStream outputStream;

    public TestClientThread() throws JAXBException, UnknownHostException, IOException, InterruptedException, XMLStreamException,
            ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(XMLProtocol.class);
        jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
        protocol = new XMLProtocol();
        outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

        new Thread(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                protocol.setContent("Hello Server. Message number^" + i);
                protocol.setStatus(ChatCommands.MSG.getCommandCode());
                jaxbMarshaller.marshal(protocol, outputStream);
            }
            protocol.setContent("Hello Server. Message number^");
            protocol.setStatus(ChatCommands.LOGOUT.getCommandCode());
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(protocol, outputStream);


/*          socket.shutdownInput();
            socket.shutdownOutput();
            socket.close();
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();*/

        } catch (JAXBException  e) {
            LOG.trace("Error in marshaling ");

        }
    }
}

class TestServerThread implements Runnable {
    private Server server;

    public TestServerThread() {
        new Thread(this);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            server.main(null);
        } catch (IOException | JAXBException | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e) {
            Assert.assertFalse(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got these errors in the past too.
I think, that these errors caused by a non synchronized resource. But I couldnt find something in the javadoc that points me to an mistake.

So I decided to use jersey/grizzly for connection handling, data encoding etc.
If you're interessted in, read my comment there: [MultiClient / Server. Handle communications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624752/multiclient-server-handle-communications/11625335#11625335)

But, I would appreciated, if someone can tell us how to use plain old sockets in a heavy concurrent environment.

Comment: Year you were totally right, it was problem in synchronizing access to the map. So i review my code for synchro problems... And now it works perfect.