# Socket write error when i connect multiple client to java server simultaneously

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I am creating a desktop application in which multiple clients have to connect to the server using socket connection between them. I successfully connected them but the problem occurs when i connect multiple client simultaneously to the server, sever got an error "**socket write error**" 
my code is below plz suggest me an answer..

```
public class SocketConnection implements Runnable {
    // password of oracle database

    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    Socket socket = null;
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    DBConnection dbConnection;


    public SocketConnection() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        dbConnection = new DBConnection();

        if (con != null) {

            serverSocket = dbConnection.createSocket();

            if (serverSocket != null) {

                System.out.println("Server Started. Looking for the connections.");
                System.out.println("Listening Port:8888.......");
            }



            Thread t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (true) {
            try {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Connection Accepted");
                Connect m_connect = new Connect(clientSocket);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    public class Connect implements Runnable {
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        Thread t = null;
        private ResultSet res1;
        private ResultSet res2;
        Statement stmt;
        private File mkFolder;

        public Connect(Socket clientSocke) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.clientSocket = clientSocke;

            try {

                stmt = con.createStatement();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(
                        clientSocket.getInputStream());
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                        clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                System.out.println("Connection established::"
                        + clientSocket.getInetAddress());
                String pass = dataInputStream.readUTF();
                System.out.println(pass);
                if (pass.equals("1")) {
                    //here is read n write operation

                } else if (pass.equals("3")) {

                    //here is read n write operation

                } else if (pass.equals("2")) {

                    //here is read n write operation

                } else if (pass.equals("4")) {
                    //here is read n write operation

                } else if (pass.equals("5")) {
                    //here is read n write operation

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (socket != null) {
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (dataOutputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        dataOutputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (dataInputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        dataInputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (stmt != null) {
                    try {
                        stmt.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }




    }

}
```

Comment: Do you know what line is throwing that error?

Comment: I Got error in read and write operation..

Comment: Which read/write operation, *in the code* is throwing that error? It's obvious that it's a read/write operation since that's in the title of the error message.

Comment: here is my stack trace..

java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeUTF(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeUTF(Unknown Source)
 at ConnectOracle$SocketConnection$Connect.run(ConnectOracle.java:529)

n line number 529 is..
dataOutputStream.writeUTF(res2         .getString(t)); in pass=1;

Answer (score -1):

Why you are doing this in that low-level way? Choose an well documented API and communicate through it!

Did you already read articles like this: [Multithread client server chat on sockets. Load test. recv failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123530/multithread-client-server-chat-on-sockets-load-test-recv-failed/11716222#11716222)

Comment: i dont know.. how to implement this

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't teach you developing a protocol. Why youre not using RMI or other? Then you can send stupid simple pojos representing your commands and returning some data.But I would never implement this, what you try, by myself

Comment: Thanx for ur consideration.!!
but my problem is solved now..
n i'll try to learn this also..